# Cannot clear animation on a view, Android?

Tags: android, animation

So I use this method to animate a `view` for an infinite time:

```
    private void animateView (final View view) {
        final Animation animationIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fade_in);
        final Animation animationOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);

        animationIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                view.startAnimation(animationOut);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        animationOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                view.startAnimation(animationIn);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        view.startAnimation(animationIn);
    }
```

I used this method because it seemed that `animation.setRepeatMode()` and `animation.setRepeatCount()` were not working and after a bit search I found out they are basically buggy.

But when I call `myView.clearAnimation()`, it keeps animating. What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that calling `clearAnimation()` *ends* the current animation... which triggers your `onAnimationEnd()` method, starting a new animation.

I would create a boolean flag to track whether or not the animations should loop, and turn it off when you want to cancel your animations.

- Create the flag (default to true)

```
private boolean shouldRepeatAnimations = true;
```

- Read the flag to determine if your animations should loop:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    if (shouldRepeatAnimations) {
        view.startAnimation(animationIn);
    }
}
```

- When you want to cancel the animation, also turn the flag off:

```
shouldRepeatAnimations = false;
view.clearAnimation();
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks dude!